# Best practices for supporting different environments in vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have an app that sometimes is used in a native environment on bare metal and other times used in a VM started with vagrant up. The only difference is a few config files. What is the accepted way of getting the VM version of the config files in place when a vagrant up is run?

I tried running a setup.sh script that uses here docs and sed, but it seems like the script does not run. I have this line in my Vagrantfile:

```
web.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh"
```

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo running setup.sh
cat > test_file << EOM
this was written by setup.sh
EOM

cat > admin/test_file << EOM
file in lower level dir
EOM

sed -e's/\/\/ \$secure_url/$secure_url/' -e's/\/\/ \$unix_path/$unix_path/' admin/configuration.php > admin/configuration.php.vagrant
mv admin/configuration.php.vagrant admin/configuration.php
```

Here is what I see on vagrant up:

```
    web: Running: /var/folders/fw/2zgstcx50zx28q4vb2j_lm740000gn/T/vagrant-shell20170710-10653-nuvcch.sh
==> web: running setup.sh
==> web: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 22: admin/test_file: No such file or directory
==> web: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 34: admin/configuration.php.vagrant: No such file or directory
==> web: mv: 
==> web: cannot stat `admin/configuration.php.vagrant'
==> web: : No such file or directory
```

test_file does not get created
the admin dir exists and it's 777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will only run once when the VM is initialised

If you want to run the script each time you start up the VM you will need to run this instead

```
web.vm.provision :shell, :path => "setup.sh", :run => 'always', privileged: false
```

when running with `privileged: false` option, your script will run with `vagrant` user, otherwise it gets run with `root`

Comment: Thanks. That gets my script to run, but it does not seem to work. It has a here doc in it to create a file and I can see the script runs but the file does not get created. There is no error on that, but no file. If I run the script by hand the file is created. I have checked and it's not a permission issue.

The second issue I have is that I am trying to access a file in a subdir, and I get "No such file or directory" even though the path to the file does exist and is accessible.

Comment: yep because by default script are run with root user, while when you run the script by hand you run with vagrant user

Comment: I am taking about when it runs from vagrant up. When I run it by hand I am running it outside the VM as myself. When it runs from vagrant up, since I ran the command I assumed it would also run as myself. In any case I chmod'ed the dir to 777 as a test and it still did not work.

Comment: I edited the answer with using `privileged: false` option in your provisioning script

Comment: with `privileged: false` I get a permissioned denied error. With `privileged: true' I do not get an error, but the file is not created. That is for the file at the top level. For the file in the subdir I get no such file in both cases.

Comment: ok, maybe you want to show your script, its getting a bit difficult to work on assumption

Comment: I added the script to the post.

Comment: I resolved this by using /vagrant in all file accesses, e.g. `/vagrant/test_file` and `/vagrant/admin/configuration.php.vagrant`. It's all working as desired now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very well documented but the provision method can get a run parameter (by default set to 'once'):

```
web.vm.provision :shell, run: 'always', :path => "setup.sh"
```